# Error 401 al hacer conexión con WEBSERVICE

Tags: php, curl

Hola buenos días tengo problemas con la conexión a un WebService. Para comprobar que los datos que me pasaron fueran correctos hice una conexión con Postman, como resultado si obtuve respuesta por parte del servidor, después pase esos mismos datos a Curl PHP, lo que me dio como respuesta fue con error 401 y otros datos más, otros chicos corrieron el script con los que hacen pruebas directamente en el servidor y me hicieron el comentario que a ellos también les devuelve el 401 con los otros datos que también obtengo, pero algo curioso que me dijeron es que después de correr el script y obtener el 401 si les da respuesta el servidor. Como evidencia me enviaron una captura de pantalla para ver cómo es que se corre el script en el servidor.

A continuación les anexo todo lo que he hecho en Curl PHP de forma local para poder obtener respuesta del servidor.

> Conexión exitosa Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Conexión fallida Curl PHP

```
<?php

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <methodCall>
     <methodName>listAccounts</methodName>
     <params>
      <param>
       <value>
        <struct>
         <member>
          <name>i_account</name>
          <value>
           <int>2763</int>
          </value>
         </member>
        </struct>
       </value>
      </param>
     </params>
    </methodCall>';

    $url = 'https://sip.serv.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi';

    $username = 'ABACOM';
    $password = 'contraseña';

    $credentials = "{$username}:{$password}";

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //Tipo de peticion POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // Then, after your curl_exec call:
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    print_r($header_size);
    $opcion1 = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    print_r($opcion1);
    $header = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
    print_r($header);
    $body = substr($result, $header_size);
    print_r($body);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Conexión exitosa directamente con el servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos

Comment: En la Autorizathion estás manejando Token?

Comment: Desconozco o al menos no me han comentado nada de eso, según yo no porque no inserte nada de toke en el Postman

Comment: Esta algo raro porque a ellos también les devuelve el 401 pero después ya les contesta el servidor correctamente.
Como se sabría yo que es por token?

Comment: Utilizas una url https, estos parámetros CURLOPT_SSL_ están bien configurados?

Comment: Si utilizo https y esos parámetros los encontré en internet en varios foros.

Comment: Aquí lo tiene diferente. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306196/phps-curl-how-to-connect-over-https

Comment: Ya me había topado con ese post y lo hice cambiando los valores por los que indicaba la publicación y de igual manera me manda el mismo error.

Comment: Hola Javier, hay algunos bugs reportados según los cuales la autentificación digest, que es la que usas para este caso, tiene problemas con `cURL` ([ver aquí](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70101)). No sé si sea tu caso, dinos qué versión de PHP y de cURL estás usando. En una pregunta reportaban que había dos respuestas, una `401` y otra `200` y mostraban una forma un poco chapuza de engañar para obtener la segunda respuesta que es la buena. No sé, dado que es algo que atañe a la seguridad creo sería mejor que consultes a los programadores de la API o Servicio Web.